# pandas map to next week's monday

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a canonical/easy way to map a date/list of dates to their respective next Monday in pandas?
E.g. given a list of 7 days, return a list of 7 days where Monday stays the same and Tuesday-Sunday get mapped to the next Monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Week offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#parametric-offsets):

```
In [11]: days = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')

In [12]: days + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=0)
Out[12]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07',
               '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14',
               '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14',
               '2019-01-14', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21',
               '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21',
               '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28',
               '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-02-04',
               '2019-02-04', '2019-02-04', '2019-02-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

To fix Mondays:

```
In [13]: days + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=0, n=0)
Out[13]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07',
               '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-14',
               '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14',
               '2019-01-14', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21',
               '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21',
               '2019-01-21', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28',
               '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-28',
               '2019-02-04', '2019-02-04', '2019-02-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note: You can use a different number for a different weekday (e.g. 2 for Tuesday), and you can also subtract to get the previous Monday.

Comment: Maybe we still need np.where here, since 2019-01-07 should keep as it .

Comment: @Wen-Ben you can use normalize (though it doesn't really seem to be documented)

Comment: @Wen-Ben wait, maybe I was miscounting/you miscounted, surely 01-07 stays the same as is in the first example? Edit: No, I can't count.

Comment: I mean in your example , the first 7 dates should be 2019-01-07

Comment: @Wen-Ben got it, I couldn't count. Fixed (without where ;) )

Comment: no need to subtract, just use `n=0`, i.e. `Week(n=0, weekday=0)`

Comment: @root wow, totally missed/glossed over that argument. Needs some documentation!

Comment: yeah, could certainly be documented better; I think the only place it's mentioned is hidden away in the [anchored offset semantics](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics) section

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` with `weekday`

```
s=pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2019-02-11',periods=7))
s=pd.Series(np.where(s.dt.weekday!=0,s+pd.to_timedelta(7-s.dt.weekday,'D'),s))
s
0   2019-02-11
1   2019-02-18
2   2019-02-18
3   2019-02-18
4   2019-02-18
5   2019-02-18
6   2019-02-18
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this, but looking at documentation for [Timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), it looks like you can do something like

```
my_timestamp += datetime.timedelta(days=(7 - my_timestamp.weekday())%7)
```